# Redirect from Vaadin to HttpServlet

Tags: java, servlets, vaadin

i work with very old web app (15+ years) that was made using HttpServlets and applet, i want to replace applet that work as menu (it has links to different HttpServlets) with Vaadin Tree (now Tree appear). But now i have problem: when user click trenode it should redirect to certain HttpServlet.
All HttpServlets not registred in web.xml they are called one from another through html tags.
Also due server restrictions i can use Vaadin 6 only.

```
tree.addListener(new ItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void itemClick(ItemClickEvent event) {
         if(event.getItemId().equals("Report")) {
             //redirect to HttpServlet 
         }
     }
});
```

First, I tried mad idea: implemented HttpServletRequestListener and in onRequestEnd() redirect to HttpServlet, but that dont work.

```
public void onRequestEnd(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
     try {
          response.sendRedirect(redirectTo);
     } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

My second thoufg was to use

```
setLogoutURL("/servleturl"); 
getMainWindow().getApplication().close();
```

but it gives error:

Requested resource [VAADIN/widgetsets/com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.DefaultWidgetSet/servleturl] not found from filesystem or through class loader. Add widgetset and/or theme JAR to your classpath or add files to WebContent/VAADIN folder.

Then i tried do it using jsp:

```
 <html>
 <head>
    <title>JSP include with parameters example</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    REDIRECT TO SERVLET 
    name="<%= request.getParameter("name") %>"
    <%
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        if(name != null &&  name!="")
        {
            response.sendRedirect(name);
        }
     %>
</body>
</html>
```

and call

```
setLogoutURL("../../../redirect.jsp?name=asd");
```

it just returns HTTP 404 but server show that inintialization succesful.

Then i tried to register in web.xml that jsp as Servlet and change setLougoutURL but error same as above.

When i copied redirect.jsp to WebContent/VAADIN change call

```
setLogoutURL("../../redirect.jsp?name=asd");
```

page show

```
REDIRECT TO SERVLET name=""
```

as Parameter name is empty so jsp dont make redirection.

Server is WAS 6.1 if it maybe a reason of problem.

Any ideas how to redirect to servlet? I already dont have any ideas. But maybe change Vaadin to something different (i used because i worked with it earlier)?

Comment: As long as your other servlets are not registered with a URL you won't be able to access them from vaadin.

Comment: i tried to register them. it doesnt help